# How to disable the Apptentive "Do you love _____?" dialog

Tags: android-library, apptentive

How do you disable the Apptentive dialog that randomly pops up asking: "Do you love [App name]?"

Right now it's showing the title of another project and may need reconfiguring on the web, but for now I just want to disable it in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using version `1.4.0+`, then you would need to go into `Interactions -> Ratings Prompt -> Launch`, and pause the ratings prompt.

If you are using a previous version, go to `Interactions -> Ratings Prompt -> Legacy Clients`, and uncheck Enable the `Ratings Prompt for people on the legacy SDK`.

As to why it is displaying the wrong app name, that can be for one of two reasons:

1. The app name specified in the `android:label` element of your manifest's `<application>` tag is incorrect.
2. The name you have set in `App Settings -> App Settings -> App Display Name` is incorrect.